# 2 for 1 argument error Railstutorial.org section 10.22

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Currently I am on listing 10.22 in the railstutorial.org book. When I follow the example in listing 10.22 and type this into the user.rb file

```
# Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
def authenticated?(attribute, token)
  digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
  return false if digest.nil?
  BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
end
```

My test suite is supposed to throw a 2 for 1 argument error.  It does not even though authenticated? only takes 1 argument in the sessions_helper.rb file:

```
 # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

Furthermore, when I do add in 2 arguments as per the instructions:

```
 # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

It does throw a 2 for 1 error, and my test suite is red, while the instructions say that it should be green.  Is this an error in the book?
Also when I edit the user_test.rb file to read as follows:

```
test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
  assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
end
```

bundle exec rake test throws 3 errors.

Comment: Quite likely you have both versions of `authenticated?` method - one which takes a single parameter, and a second one that takes two parameters - defined in the same file. When a method is defined twice, the last one overrides the first one. My guess is that `authenticated?(attribute, token)` is defined above `authenticated?(remember_token)` in `user.rb` file, and that is what is causing this behavior.

Comment: Glad to help :-) Added the same as an answer for others benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that `authenticated?(attribute, token)` was defined above `authenticated?(remember_token)` in `user.rb` file, and that is what is causing this behavior.